# CheckAll CheckBox Jquery div

Tags: jquery, checkbox

```
<div id="tree">
        <ul>
            <li>
                <input type="checkbox"/> Root
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <input type="checkbox"/> Child 1
                        <ul>
                            <li><input type="checkbox"/> Subchild 1</li>
                            <li><input type="checkbox"/> Subchild 2</li>
                            <li><input type="checkbox"/> Subchild 3</li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <input type="checkbox"/> Child 2
                        <ul>
                            <li><input type="checkbox"/> Subchild 1</li>
                            <li><input type="checkbox"/> Subchild 2</li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>​
```

Above is html code where there is a tree with parent and child nodes.

This works well. But if all the sub node are checked then root/parent    has to be automatically checked.

And also if all the sub node are unchecked then root/parent has to be automatically unchecked. 
How do I achieve this?

Jquery

```
   $(document).ready(function() {    
       $("#tree input:checkbox").change(function() {
       var val = $(this).attr("checked");
       $(this).parent().find("input:checkbox").each(function() {
          if (val) {
             $(this).attr("checked", "checked");
          } 
         else {
            $(this).removeAttr("checked");
         }
     });    
  });
```

});​

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to work correctly (For both checked/unchecked status):

```
$(function(){
    $("#tree input:checkbox").change(function () {
        var $this = $(this), val = this.checked, $parent = $(this.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode);

        $this.parent().find("input:checkbox").each(function () {
            this.checked = val;
        });

        checkChildren($parent);
    });

    function checkChildren($node) {
        var allChecked = null;

        $node.find("ul input:checkbox").each(function(){
            if (null === allChecked) allChecked = this.checked;

            if (allChecked !== this.checked) {
                allChecked = null;
                return false;
            }
        });

        if (allChecked !== null) {
            $node.find(">input:checkbox").prop("checked", allChecked);

            var $parent = $node.parent().parent();

            if ($parent.length) checkChildren($parent);
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: This works fine but, if even one of the subnodes is checked then parent node should also be checked automatically.

Comment: Hm, try replacing `checkChildren` with `function checkChildren($node) {
  var setCheck = false;
  
  $node.find("ul input:checkbox").each(function(){
   if (this.checked) {
    setCheck = true;
    return false;
   }
  });
  
  if (setCheck) $node.find(">input:checkbox").prop("checked", setCheck);

  var $parent = $node.parent().parent();
   
  if ($parent.length) checkChildren($parent);
 }`. Is that what you need?

Comment: Ya, but now in the new code if all the subnodes are unchecked then parent is not unchecked. This should be corrected. Can you help with this. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

When all sub-child Nodes are checked, then its parent will be also checked.  Here is the code:

```
 var io = $(this).parent().parent();
    var lidtOfIO = io.find('input[type="checkbox"]');
         var listOfCheckedCBox = $(this).parent().parent().find('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').length;
         if (listOfCheckedCBox == lidtOfIO.length)
            $(io).parent().find('input[type="checkbox"]').prop('checked', true);
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Ft35Q/10/)

Comment: @Bharadwaj valid point I missed to check it http://jsfiddle.net/Ft35Q/11/.. let me fix it

Answer (score 0):

Use like this:

```
$('#tree input:checkbox').each(function(){
 if($(this).is(':checked')){
  $('#tree input.first').prop('checked',true);
}
});
```

I've added input.first in the code as if you should add a class for that input to which you want to check if all checked.

Answer (score 0):

Please below jquery code

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("input[type='checkbox']").change(function () {                
        var val = $(this).is(":checked");
        $(this).parent().find("input[type='checkbox']").each(function () {            
                $(this).prop("checked", val);            
        });
    });
});
```

Also [jsfiddle url](http://jsfiddle.net/w7wN2/)